# How can I protect the ester group from reduction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

If I process this reaction the NaBH4 will also reduced the ester group to alcohol. I want to convert the Nitro (-NO2) functional group to Amine (-NH2) without disturbing the Ester group. So, my question is that, Which protecting agent can be used here to convert Me-3-Nitrobenzoate into Me-3-Aminobenzoate. I will appreciate, if someone could help me please.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use SnCl<sub>2</sub>.2 H<sub>2</sub>O in EtOAc or EtOH as described by [Bellamy & Ou](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0040403901800411) as the ester group is untouched by the reaction conditions. I have used this method many times in high yield.

Various other methods, such as hydrogenation over 5% Pd-C or Pt in EtOAc or EtOH; or refluxing in ethanol with [indium with ammonium chloride](https://www.thieme-connect.com/products/ejournals/abstract/10.1055/s-1998-1837) or [sodium dithionite](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/chemicals/reductions/sodiumhydrosulfite-sodiumdithionite.shtm) will also work.

Comment: @SUBHAN The workup into ice/water/EtOAc will initially give an emulsion. The trick to gettting it to separate is to keep adding conc NaOH soln until you get two phases